# Closing a python program window leaves program still running in the background

Tags: python

I made a program, which uses tkinter to create a window where stuff happens. It contains images and loops to constantly shift and move the images.

Now, when I close the window, the scripts are still running and it creates error messages that it has nowhere to place the images with new coordinates.

I think that the loops are still running. So my question is, how do I close the program all together after clicking the x on the window. Is there a way to bind the x(close window) to terminate the program, or cat n ibe done inside a code, to see when the tkinter window is closed(to me this way seems to be bad, because it would keep checking for if the window is still existing or not).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `sys.exit()` will always close terminate your program ... my guess is you have a top level window that is hidden rather than destroyed somewhere

Comment: Some code showing what you do would help.

Comment: Actually I got it fixed by removing threads. It was initiating threads with a Timer, forcing it still count down and execute after some time passing. Replacing threads with root.after() seems to work very well and no additional importing is required. Thank you for your replies! :)

Comment: You can answer your own question, or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue caused by a top level window I had created and withdrawn but didn't destroy.  Properly destroying it fixed my issue.